# Transitioning from XIB files to Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xib, storyboard

I currently have an XCode project that uses XIBs and would like to start using Storyboards.  Is there a good way to move my XIB files into the Storyboard?

Comment: The alleged “duplicate” of this question actually asks for the opposite…

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually one view controller at a time.

1. Copy the view from xib (⌘ c).

[image]

2. Go to storyboard and create a new view controller in it. Then select the view of that view controller and hit paste (⌘ v).

[image]