# Transitioning to storyboards

Tags: uistoryboard, ios5

I have a project with multiple xibs, and since I'm developing for iOS 5 API's, I want to transition to storyboard.
I couldn't find any tutorials about this thing, only about opening a **new** project with storyboard.

Is there a way to transition completely to only storyboard in a project **without** xibs and **without** opening a new project for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

~> This will be helpful to you.

[Transitioning from XIB files to Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798400/transitioning-from-xib-files-to-storyboard)

~> And also have a look in this Apple's document.

[Converting to Storyboards Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/_index.html)